# Spring MVC - upload file shows The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-security

When I upload file with another details using form sumbmition, it shows an error HTTP Status 400 -
type Status report
message
description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

jsp page

```
         <form:form method="POST" action="addbanners?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" modelAttribute="banner" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2>New Banner</h2>
    <table>
    <tr><td>Banner Name</td>
    <td><form:input type="text" name="thematicdayid" id="thematicdayid" path="bannerName" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Banner Image</td>
    <td><form:input name="uploadBanner" type="file" id="uploadBanner" path="bannerImage"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnAddBanner">Add</button></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
```

filecontroller.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addbanners", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addbanners(@ModelAttribute Banner banner,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){

    System.out.println("File"+file);
    ImageUpload imageUpload=new ImageUpload();
    if(!file.isEmpty())
    {
    String path=context.getRealPath("");
    String imagename=imageUpload.uploadImage(file,path);
    banner.setBannerImage(imagename);

    filewriterServices.saveBannerDetails(banner);
    }
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("filepage");
    return model;
}
```

I add below details in root-context.xml

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by changing

```
public ModelAndView addbanners(@ModelAttribute Banner banner,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) to

public ModelAndView addbanners(@ModelAttribute Banner banner,@RequestParam("uploadBanner") MultipartFile file)
```

and change

```
<form:input name="uploadBanner" type="file" id="uploadBanner" path="bannerImage"/> to 
<input name="uploadBanner" type="file" id="uploadBanner" path="bannerImage"/>
```

and thank you @Akash Rajbanshi to help me to find my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public ModelAndView addbanners(@ModelAttribute Banner banner,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
```

to

```
public ModelAndView addbanners(@ModelAttribute Banner banner,@RequestParam("uploadBanner") MultipartFile file)
```